# Standard Android vector icon set

Tags: android, xml, icons

I can't seem to understand how to use Android's standard icons.

In the app template I'm using, I can see a custom vector for a photo icon:

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0"/>
    <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2H9zm3,15c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z"/>
</vector>
```

But I'm trying to find a similar thing for the 'Person' icon but can't find it anywhere.

Surely I don't have to manually create this image and there is somewhere I can go to use a pre-existing one?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Android doesn't really have much in the way of standard icons built into the OS.  You can download a variety of icons from their webpage at https://fonts.google.com/icons

Comment: I can see how to download the SVG or PNG versions of each icon but is there anywhere to get samples of vectors for such icons? Someone must have drawn then at some point in the past I would presume?

Comment: SVG is the vector of the graphic.  It's Standard Vector Graphic format.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the drawables folder, then left click, and add vector asset. Then you can search up and choose what vector icon you want

Comment: Any idea a good source for vector icons? I can't seem to find any XML samples that define the vectors for standard icon sets?